# How to groupby only the top n% rows of another column by group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, percentile

I have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01','01','01','01','01','02','02','02','02','02','02','03','03','03'], 'ID': ['a','b','c','d','e','a','b','e','f','g','h','b','e','g'], 'RESULT': [5,6,7,4,8,2,2,4,7,13,2,6,7,7], 'SALES': [100,150,120,130,200,140,150,100,120,110,180,170,120,100]})
```

[image]

I want to groupby the average of results by **date**, but only for the IDs that have the top 20% **sales**. Then, the expected results should be:

[image]

My original df is much larger, about 4,5 million rows, so I would need an efficient code.

I found other similar answers, but none of them address my problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: not sure if it'll be fast enough but it should be

```
df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x : x[(x['SALES'] >= x['SALES'].quantile(0.8))]['RESULT'].mean())
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way by `rank()`:

```
df[df.groupby('Date')['SALES'].rank(pct=True).gt(0.8)].groupby('Date')['RESULT'].mean()
```

---

```
Date
01    8
02    2
03    6
```